# how to see existing trigger in nvaicat for oracle

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle11g, oracle10g, navicat

i am trying to create a trigger like

```
CREATE  trigger trg_DEPT_ORGS_id
    before insert on DEPT_ORGS
    for each row
    begin
        select DEPT_ORGS_id_seq.nextval
            into :new.dep_id
            from dual;
    end;
```

but it is showing an error `trigger exists already`. How can I see the triggers.

Answer (score 1):

You can populate the list of triggers in a schema by `all_triggers` table.

```
desc all_triggers;
```

---

```
Name                   
 -----------------
 OWNER                  
 TRIGGER_NAME           
 TRIGGER_TYPE           
 TRIGGERING_EVENT       
 TABLE_OWNER            
 BASE_OBJECT_TYPE       
 TABLE_NAME             
 COLUMN_NAME            
 REFERENCING_NAMES
 WHEN_CLAUSE            
 STATUS                 
 DESCRIPTION            
 ACTION_TYPE            
 TRIGGER_BODY
```

---

```
Select trigger_name from all_triggers where trigger_name='trg_DEPT_ORGS_id'
```